# How to create web-element at browser extension(Chrome) in the foreground & in every place of the document?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

This image spawns at the bottom of document. I think, that humanity have options to decide this, because we have many types of extensions, for example, online-translators of the text, that display many information near to dedicated text. I dont`t think that there all realised through popups.

```
const body = document.querySelector('body')

let someimage = document.createElement("img");
        
someimage.src = "user_src"

someimage.style.position = "relative";
someimage.style.float.left
someimage.style.top = 0
someimage.style.zIndex = 999
let div1 = document.createElement("div")
div1.append(someimage)
document.body.append(div1)
```

Comment: Use `fixed` instead of `relative` and `0x7FFFFFFF` instead of `999`. BTW You can inspect those extensions yourself in devtools.

Comment: @wOxxOm Why `0x7FFFFFFF `? It works, but its just more complicated than actual numbers? Just curious.

Comment: It's the biggest allowed number for z-index in hexadecimal notation.